# Draggable image in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, image, iframe, ckeditor, draggable

I have a problem, I can't make a image inside **CKEditor** draggable. I tried many things like
`$('img').draggable();` with timeout and so on. I can't get the image draggable.

I also tried to inject a `<script>` tag with a `.js` file with `$('img').draggable();` in the iframe, but no errors in console, and no working system.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Why do you want to make the image draggable? You want the image to adjust itself relative to content of the editor or something?

Comment: Now you can't move the image to where you want and place it correctly. It's kinda annoying and impossible to get the image on the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call javascript on elements inside ckeditor because it's within an iframe. You will have to create or find a plugin for ckeditor.